# Sort the result of multiple flat maps in RXJava

Tags: android, facebook, sorting, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm fetching facebook posts with the following code (facebook4j library):

```
public List<BatchResponse> getAllPosts() {
  BatchRequests<BatchRequest> batch = new BatchRequests<>();
  batch.add(new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, "USERID/feed?limit=5"));
  batch.add(new BatchRequest(RequestMethod.GET, "USERID2/feed?limit=5"));
  List<BatchResponse> results = facebook.executeBatch(batch);
  return results;
}
```

Then I'm using RXJava to parse the code:

```
 Observable.defer(() -> Observable.just(getAllPosts()))
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .flatMap(Observable::from)
      .map(BatchResponse::asResponseList)
      .flatMap(Observable::from)
      .map(rawPost -> DataObjectFactory.createPost(rawPost.toString()))
      .toSortedList(MainActivity::compareModel)
      .flatMap(Observable::from)
      .map(Post::getMessage)
      .subscribe(Log::v, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```

I tried to sort it using [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565447/sort-collection-of-objects-with-reactive-extensions-in-java)

```
private static Integer compareModel(Post car1, Post car2) {
    return car1.getCreatedTime().compareTo(car2.getCreatedTime());
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't sort all posts, but it only sorts the posts of one user (/one batch request). I figured that it is because of the batch requests get executed in succession because of the flat maps. I don't know how to solve it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that your issue is a flatMap problem. `toSortedList` will have to wait that your `Observable` complete before trying to sort it. You may want to add some logs just before (thanks to `doOnNext(evt -> /** log something **/)` for example.

I think you may want to check what return `asReponseList` and `createPost` method. It may not return everything.

Please found bellow your code with some small updates (see the `flatMapIterable` which do the same things as `flatMap(Observable::from)`)

```
  Observable.fomCallable(() -> getAllPosts())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMapIterable(l -> l)
            .flatMapIterable(BatchResponse::asResponseList)
            .map(rawPost -> DataObjectFactory.createPost(rawPost.toString()))
            .doOnNext(evt -> LOGGER.debug(evt))
            .toSortedList(MainActivity::compareModel)
            .flatmapIterable(l -> l)
            .map(Post::getMessage)
            .subscribe(Log::v, Throwable::printStackTrace);
```